# Spring MVC 3.1 RESTful Controller

Tags: spring, rest, jakarta-ee

Im about to write a Spring MVC Controller to serve/receive HTML forms and JSON. The best way seems to be to use a RESTful controller, but as its the first one Ive written I want to do it right!

Is it possible to have one method which will return either a view to be rendered by InternalResourceViewResolver if its an HTML request, or an Entity to be rendered as JSON if its an ajax request?

The same goes for updates, can you write a single controller method that will accept either an object thats been converted from incoming JSON or a @Valid object from an HTML form, depending on the content-type?

I seems to me you must be able to, otherwise why have support for DELETE and PUT in HTML forms using the sf taglib form element? Just can't seem to find an explanation of how to do it anywhere!

Cheers!
NFV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give this a go.

Here is what I have in my `Configuration` class:

```
@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver viewResolver() {
    final ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setOrder(1);
    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setFavorPathExtension(true);
    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setFavorParameter(true);
    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setIgnoreAcceptHeader(false);
    final Map<String, String> mediaTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mediaTypes.put("json", "application/x-json");
    mediaTypes.put("json", "text/json");
    mediaTypes.put("json", "text/x-json");
    mediaTypes.put("json", "application/json");
    mediaTypes.put("xml", "text/xml");
    mediaTypes.put("xml", "application/xml");
    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
    final List<View> defaultViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    defaultViews.add(jsonView());
    defaultViews.add(xmlView());
    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setDefaultViews(defaultViews);
    return contentNegotiatingViewResolver;
}

@Bean(name = "xStreamMarshaller")
public XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller() {
    return new XStreamMarshaller();
}

@Bean(name = "xmlView")
public MarshallingView xmlView() {
    final MarshallingView marshallingView = new MarshallingView(xStreamMarshaller());
    marshallingView.setContentType("application/xml");
    return marshallingView;
}

@Bean(name = "jsonView")
public MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView() {
    return new MappingJacksonJsonView();
}
```

And here is what goes in the `Controller`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/pets" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("pets", petRepository.findAll());
    return "pets/list";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/pets" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@Valid @RequestBody Pet pet, Model model) {
    petRepository.save(pet);
    return "redirect:pets/read/" + pet.getId();
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/pets/{petId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String read(@PathVariable Integer petId, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("pet", petRepository.findOne(petId));
    return "pets/read";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/pets" }, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String update(@Valid @RequestBody Pet pet, Model model) {
    petRepository.save(pet);
    return "redirect:pets/read/" + pet.getId();
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/pets/{orderId}" }, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void delete(@PathVariable Integer petId, Model model) {
    petRepository.delete(petId);
}
```

From my experience, you can submit an HTML form or a JSON object as a `@RequestBody`. Give it a try.

Comment: Ive tried altering my setup to be like this but just keep getting a "HTTP Status 415 - The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ()". If i remove the @RequestBody annotations it works fine (for form posts at least)

Comment: Remove the `@RequestBody` and see if HTML form and JSON submits work. I think Spring will handle that for you. Either way, when you are returning just a `String` Spring will either bounce you to a view (if acceptType is HTML) or translate any `Model` objects into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It's surely possible but I don't see why that would be useful.

In my opnion a controller method should be created for every action you will need, making a controller handle 2 different kinds of input will make this controller method complicated to read and maintain over time.

A way to do it is using consumes in @RequestMapping annotation like this, then you write 2 methods and each watches for it's kind of input.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json");
```

[source of this code](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: I see, I thought that the framework would have handled all the conversions to keep the implementation simple and DRYer. Do you know why we have the option of using DELETE and PUT methods in form  requests then? I had assumed it was so you could use the same handler methods for HTML forms but maybe I'm wrong!